# Poincaré inequality in Elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

I'm having a problem figuring out the answer to this question.
Consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = f & \mbox{in } \Omega = (0,1)^2, \newline
\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = g_N & \mbox{on } \Gamma_N = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x = 0 \}, 
\newline
u = 0 & \mbox{on } \Gamma_D = \partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma_N,
\end{cases}
$$
Suppose that the problem is solved with the same boundary conditions, but a different source term $\tilde{f}$. Call the corresponding solution $\tilde{u}$. Write the strong form of the problem that must be solved to determine $w := u - \tilde{u}$.
Then using the **Poincaré inequality**, prove that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$
\| w \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \| f - \tilde{f} \| _{L^2(\Omega)}
$$

---

Personally I already figured out how to answer the first question related to the strong form to determine $w$ but I'm struggling a bit with the second part. I think that we should use the fact that $L^2$ norm is bounded by the $H^1$ norm but I really don't know how

Comment: Try thinking about the weak formulation of the problem, and see if you can find a useful estimate that way :)

Comment: That's an interesting option, but I find it hard due to the presence of the Neumann Boundary term on the linear functional. Do you have any idea on how to treat it?

Comment: Since $\triangledown u\cdot\mathbf{n} = \triangledown \tilde{u}\cdot\mathbf{n} = g_N$ on $\Gamma_N$, we have $\triangledown w\cdot\mathbf{n} = 0$ on $\Gamma_N$, and so there shouldn't be any boundary term in the weak formulation for the problem in $w$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I was looking at the the original weak formulation. Thank you for the correction